# relieved when she did sth

Tags: word-usage

I wonder whether "relieved when she.." can be written as "relieved as she..." without affecting the meaning. It seems not but I can't tell why.

==================

> A 54-year-old woman presented with palpitations that were **relieved when she** passed gas or had a bowel movement. Computed tomography revealed the presence of the transverse colon within the pericardial cavity.

> Source: [NEJM](https://twitter.com/NEJM/status/1377984160485281795)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think substituting "as" for "when" preserves the meaning, even though both refer to timing.

"Her symptoms were relieved **when** she passed gas" implies that the symptoms went away, and then returned gradually, to be relieved again when she passed gas later.

"Her symptoms were relieved **as** she passed gas" means that the symptoms were present at all times, except for the very brief moments when she was actually in the process of passing gas. As soon as she stopped, the symptoms returned immediately. This is not the same meaning as before.